# Reference of element from a const vector

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have a function which takes in a `const std::vector<std::pair<float, cv::RotatedRect> >`

```
void fn (const std::vector < std::pair < float, cv::RotatedRect > >& vec1,
        std::vector < std::pair< float, cv::Rect> >& vec2) {
```

So When I want to take an element of `cv::RotatedRect` I do

```
cv::RotatedRect& newrotrect = vec1[cntr].second;
```

This obviously gives and error saying I tried to create a reference from a `const` member.

The question I had was :

1. what is happening and why am I not allowed to do this ?
2. What is faster, removing the `const` from the fun call (which is not ideal) or `const_cast`ing elements ?

Comment: Why not `const cv::RotatedRect& ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't store a const reference in a non-const reference without casting, because this will allow you to modify the object and the point of const is to stop you doing that.
2. Neither. Use

`const cv::RotatedRect& newrotrect = vec1[cntr].second;`

Answer (score 2):

1) You are not allowed because the `const` version of vector's access `operator[]` returns a `const` reference. This is so you cannot modify its contents. It is `const`, so that makes sense.

2) You shouldn't decide to remove `const` or not because it is "faster". You need to decide which semantics are appropriate for your code. But you can get a `const` reference:

```
const cv::RotatedRect& newrotrect = vec1[cntr].second;
```

or make a copy:

```
cv::RotatedRect newrotrect = vec1[cntr].second;
```